# How to better deal with regex capture group between HTML tags?

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to capture this content inside the html tag document in the string below. The result yields the desired match, but also a weird entry "t", the last letter before the close tag.

I'm pretty new to regex and I wonder what is going on? What should I read up about?

PS: If I remove the () brackets around the pattern, only 't' is captured. I'm not sure I can see what difference the bracket (i.e. defining a capture group) make in this case.

```
example = '''ABCDE<DOCUMENT>
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet</DOCUMENT>
EFGHIJK.'''

re.findall(r'(<DOCUMENT>(.|\s)*<\/DOCUMENT>)', example)
```

Outputs:

```
[('<DOCUMENT>\nLorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet</DOCUMENT>', 't')]
```

Comment: I get `[('<DOCUMENT>\nLorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet</DOCUMENT>', 't')]` when I run your code.

Comment: @sln yes, that is what I typed. Stack exchange took the <DOCUMENT> as actual html tags and didn't display it. Do you know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `re.DOTALL` [flag](http://xahlee.info/python/python_regex_flags.html) instead of using `\s` to capture whitespaces:

```py
re.findall(r'(<DOCUMENT>.*<\/DOCUMENT>)', example, flags = re.DOTALL)
```

### Explaining the issue

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) documentation states that:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group

You have two capturing groups (defined by the parenthesis) in your regex:

1. over all the pattern, defined by the first and last parenthesis
2. over the `.|\s` pattern

That's why the return is a list of a tuple with two elements: `\nLorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet` and `t`.

When you use the `*` *outside* the capturing group, you are actually matching it multiple times. The last time the group matches, is the last `t` of "amet" in the input string, thus `findall` returns it as the value of the capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can use this expression,

```
<DOCUMENT>(.*?)<\/DOCUMENT>
```

#### [Please see this demo for explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/4pCiAn/1/)

with `s` flag, or any of these expressions:

```
<DOCUMENT>([\s\S]*?)<\/DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>([\d\D]*?)<\/DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>([\w\W]*?)<\/DOCUMENT>
```

with `m` flag, and our problem would be likely solved.

#### [Please see this demo for explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/yPyF9v/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"<DOCUMENT>([\s\S]*?)<\/DOCUMENT>"

test_str = ("ABCDE<DOCUMENT>\n"
    "Lorem ipsum\n\n\n\n"
    "dolor sit amet</DOCUMENT>\n"
    "EFGHIJK.")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```